# Overloading lib files from gem mounted as engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, overloading

I am using a gem that is mounted as engine and want to customize some classes.
The files i want to overload are located in my local rvm dir

```
(rvmdir)/(gem)/lib/(modulename)/containers/file_to_override.rb
```

I copied the file to my app dir

```
(appdir)/lib/(modulename)/containers/file_to_override.rb
```

and customized some output.

The file Looks similar to this:

```
module (Modulename)
  module Containers
    class FileToOverride << xxx
    ...
    end
  end
end
```

But it does not seem to overload. Is it possible to override lib files in my own application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i put the file in `/config/initializer/file_to_override.rb` with the above content it works.