# how to overwrite rails engine files that are in the lib directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, overwrite, rails-engines

I want to overwrite a file of a rails engine, but that file is in that engine's lib/rails directory.  When I take the same file and drop it in my lib/rails directory it doesn't overwrite the file.  Seems like rails handles the lib directory differently than say files that are in the app directory.

Also I can't place this file in the initializer folder ([per this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248174/overloading-lib-files-from-gem-mounted-as-engine)) as the filename is the same as an exisiting file that is needed.  What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I have found to solve this problem is by adding

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/path/to/file"
```

at the end of `config/application.rb`. The pollution is minimal, and achieves the same effect as the override would.

Currently using it in a Spree project to override `lib/spree_samples.rb`.

**Edit**

Found a better way in this answer:
[Overloading lib files from gem mounted as engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248174/overloading-lib-files-from-gem-mounted-as-engine)

Essentially, put the file you want to override in your `config/initializers` directory.